# Is there a font (free or paid) that matches the one used in the original Declaration of Independence title?

Tags: font

To clarify:

I'm looking for the one that would more or less exactly match the line that reads:

> The unanimous Declaration of the thirteen united States of America

I've looked at dozens upon dozens, and every time the font is either too simple or too fancy. There's that characteristic "S" in the word "States" that must be throwing all font creators off, or something.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the font ***Declaration Blackletter*** from P22 is pretty much exact.

This is the link to the publisher's site: https://p22.com/proc.php?cass=110&id=875&return=family-Declaration

[image]